# what is Shannon entropy?

Tags: wavelet

I was reading a paper about finding optimal morlet wavelet function for CWT, and they were minimizing Shannon entropy.
what is Shannon entropy and it uses?
(specially on continuous wavelet transform)

Comment: [Entropy (information theory), introduced by Claude Shannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shannon entropy is a way of measuring the degree of unexpectedness or unpredictability of a random variable. For example rolling a die has higher entropy than flipping a coin because the die has more possible outcomes making it harder to predict. Same goes for a biased coin versus a fair coin.

Comment: For signals, it also helps quantifying the amount of information present in the signal, so that if there's only a small amount you know you can describe the signal with limited data.

Comment: check my other question about shannon entropy here plz http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/how-to-calculate-cwt-entropy @Aaron

Comment: @florian-castellane