# How to calculate CWT shannon entropy?

Tags: wavelet

I am trying to calculate shannon entropy of `CWT`. I am not sure if I am doing it right. 
Assume that $W(a_i,t), i=1;2;...;M$ is a set of wavelet coefficients. The Shannon wavelet entropy is calculated by:
$E=-\sum_{i=1}^{M}d_i log(d_i)$ $\rightarrow$   where $d_i=\frac{|W(a_i,t)|}{\sum_{j=1}^{M}W(a_j,t)}$
I am confused how to calculate $E$. for example I have a coefficient matrix with size of $M\times N$, $M$ is scales number and $N$  is time segments. first I have to calulate $d_i$, this is my main problem. this is the wavelet coefficient matrix :
 $W_{M\times N} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  w_{a_1,1} & w_{a_1,2} & \cdots & w_{a_1,N} \\
  w_{a_2,1} & w_{a_2,2} & \cdots & w_{a_2,N} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  w_{a_M,1} & w_{a_M,2} & \cdots & w_{a_M,N}
 \end{pmatrix}$

hmm i am pretty sure i am wrong, can anyone help? 
for example tell me how can i calculate $d_4$?
Here I have right a little Matlab script to calculate shannon entropy of CWT.
Is it right or wrong? and what should I do?

```
 [M,N]=size(coeffs);
for js=1:M     
Ej(js)=sum(abs(coeffs(js,:)));
end;
Etot=sum(Ej);
Pj=Ej./Etot;
%shannon entropy
shan_entr=-sum(Pj.*log(Pj));
```

Comment: What paper did you get this from?

Comment: from this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X05003913  actually the first 3 lines are from the paper, other lines are my question.

Comment: also you can look here too: http://www.iitk.ac.in/nicee/wcee/article/14_05-01-0450.PDF @Aaron

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to take the entropy of the wavelet. But if you did have a good reason for doing it I think your code is not pasted correctly. Why are there three end statements and only one loop?

Comment: Hi @Aaron I want to find optimum pairs of $f_b,f_c$ for Morlet wavelet function. so if you look [here][1] you will see why I need to calculate shannon entropy.another paper explain the method more in [here][2] too. so that's why I need to calculate shannon entropy of wavelet. and you are right about two `end`. I will correct it, I would be glad if I understand how to calculate shannon entropy for CWT. your help is much appreciated


  [1]: http://www.iitk.ac.in/nicee/wcee/article/14_05-01-0450.PDF
  [2]: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960148111000152

Comment: i want to find optimum fb and fc of morelet wavelet by using shanon entropy. but i could not calculate them...could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your code does compute the same thing as the formula from the paper.